# C matrix libraries, suited for opengl on Android (NDK)

Tags: android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I'm writing a rendering routine in C using opengl es 2.0 with NDK. I'm interested in (speed over precision) libraries for graphical-transformations on matrices, and any best practises you can recommend.

Writing my own functions is not improbable, but I thought I'd ask here before re-inventing the wheel. Thanks.

Comment: To answer my own question, I'll likely write my own routines, using this well written code as a reference. https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/registry/trunk/public/webgl/sdk/demos/google/resources/moz/matrix4x4.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)](http://glm.g-truc.net/) seems to be a nice one.

Comment: Thanks, this worked out great. Although I asked for a C library, the cpp direction is worth taking. FYI: to use this library, be sure to use the stlport, see the CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT doc for how.

Comment: I'm not able to compile it with the NDK. I get errors like `func_common.hpp:240: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'` or `func_common.inl:1217: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'` Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Get a copy of android.opengl.matrix java code from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org%24maven2@com.google.android%24android@1.5_r3@android%24opengl%24Matrix.java). 
Then change the syntax from Java to C and you are good to go. Here is the code that I've used for my own project. It is not a complete set of Opengl matrix functions, though.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.1415926f
#define normalize(x, y, z)                  \
{                                               \
        float norm = 1.0f / sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);  \
        x *= norm; y *= norm; z *= norm;        \
}
#define I(_i, _j) ((_j)+4*(_i))

void matrixSetIdentityM(float *m)
{
        memset((void*)m, 0, 16*sizeof(float));
        m[0] = m[5] = m[10] = m[15] = 1.0f;
}

void matrixSetRotateM(float *m, float a, float x, float y, float z)
{
        float s, c;

        memset((void*)m, 0, 15*sizeof(float));
        m[15] = 1.0f;

        a *= PI/180.0f;
        s = sin(a);
        c = cos(a);

        if (1.0f == x && 0.0f == y && 0.0f == z) {
                m[5] = c; m[10] = c;
                m[6] = s; m[9]  = -s;
                m[0] = 1;
        } else if (0.0f == x && 1.0f == y && 0.0f == z) {
                m[0] = c; m[10] = c;
                m[8] = s; m[2]  = -s;
                m[5] = 1;
        } else if (0.0f == x && 0.0f == y && 1.0f == z) {
                m[0] = c; m[5] = c;
                m[1] = s; m[4] = -s;
                m[10] = 1;
        } else {
                normalize(x, y, z);
                float nc = 1.0f - c;
                float xy = x * y;
                float yz = y * z;
                float zx = z * x;
                float xs = x * s;
                float ys = y * s;
                float zs = z * s;
                m[ 0] = x*x*nc +  c;
                m[ 4] =  xy*nc - zs;
                m[ 8] =  zx*nc + ys;
                m[ 1] =  xy*nc + zs;
                m[ 5] = y*y*nc +  c;
                m[ 9] =  yz*nc - xs;
                m[ 2] =  zx*nc - ys;
                m[ 6] =  yz*nc + xs;
                m[10] = z*z*nc +  c;
        }
}

void matrixMultiplyMM(float *m, float *lhs, float *rhs)
{
        float t[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                register const float rhs_i0 = rhs[I(i, 0)];
                register float ri0 = lhs[ I(0,0) ] * rhs_i0;
                register float ri1 = lhs[ I(0,1) ] * rhs_i0;
                register float ri2 = lhs[ I(0,2) ] * rhs_i0;
                register float ri3 = lhs[ I(0,3) ] * rhs_i0;
                for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
                        register const float rhs_ij = rhs[ I(i,j) ];
                        ri0 += lhs[ I(j,0) ] * rhs_ij;
                        ri1 += lhs[ I(j,1) ] * rhs_ij;
                        ri2 += lhs[ I(j,2) ] * rhs_ij;
                        ri3 += lhs[ I(j,3) ] * rhs_ij;
                }
                t[ I(i,0) ] = ri0;
                t[ I(i,1) ] = ri1;
                t[ I(i,2) ] = ri2;
                t[ I(i,3) ] = ri3;
        }
        memcpy(m, t, sizeof(t));
}

void matrixScaleM(float *m, float x, float y, float z)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
                m[i] *= x; m[4+i] *=y; m[8+i] *= z;
        }
}

void matrixTranslateM(float *m, float x, float y, float z)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
                m[12+i] += m[i]*x + m[4+i]*y + m[8+i]*z;
        }
}

void matrixRotateM(float *m, float a, float x, float y, float z)
{
        float rot[16], res[16];
        matrixSetRotateM(rot, a, x, y, z);
        matrixMultiplyMM(res, m, rot);
        memcpy(m, res, 16*sizeof(float));
}

void matrixLookAtM(float *m,
                float eyeX, float eyeY, float eyeZ,
                float cenX, float cenY, float cenZ,
                float  upX, float  upY, float  upZ)
{
        float fx = cenX - eyeX;
        float fy = cenY - eyeY;
        float fz = cenZ - eyeZ;
        normalize(fx, fy, fz);
        float sx = fy * upZ - fz * upY;
        float sy = fz * upX - fx * upZ;
        float sz = fx * upY - fy * upX;
        normalize(sx, sy, sz);
        float ux = sy * fz - sz * fy;
        float uy = sz * fx - sx * fz;
        float uz = sx * fy - sy * fx;

        m[ 0] = sx;
        m[ 1] = ux;
        m[ 2] = -fx;
        m[ 3] = 0.0f;
        m[ 4] = sy;
        m[ 5] = uy;
        m[ 6] = -fy;
        m[ 7] = 0.0f;
        m[ 8] = sz;
        m[ 9] = uz;
        m[10] = -fz;
        m[11] = 0.0f;
        m[12] = 0.0f;
        m[13] = 0.0f;
        m[14] = 0.0f;
        m[15] = 1.0f;
        matrixTranslateM(m, -eyeX, -eyeY, -eyeZ);
}

void matrixFrustumM(float *m, float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far)
{
        float r_width  = 1.0f / (right - left);
        float r_height = 1.0f / (top - bottom);
        float r_depth  = 1.0f / (near - far);
        float x = 2.0f * (near * r_width);
        float y = 2.0f * (near * r_height);
        float A = 2.0f * ((right+left) * r_width);
        float B = (top + bottom) * r_height;
        float C = (far + near) * r_depth;
        float D = 2.0f * (far * near * r_depth);

        memset((void*)m, 0, 16*sizeof(float));
        m[ 0] = x;
        m[ 5] = y;
        m[ 8] = A;
        m[ 9] = B;
        m[10] = C;
        m[14] = D;
        m[11] = -1.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The GLM math library has a lot more than just the transforms and other matrix operations. For example, it has GLSL style mix() api that can be used to interpolate values before sending them down to your shaders.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but possibly relevant to those who choose to use C:

I've found a single-file header that has all the linear functionality required written out nicely.

https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h/blob/master/linmath.h

It contains all of the required matrix/vector types, and works fine with the Android NDK/GL2. For instance:

```
mat4x4 projection;
mat4x4 modelview;

// other stuff such as initialization etc

mat4x4_frustum(projection, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0.5, 100);
mat4x4_translate(modelview, 0, 0, -1);

// ...

// Render Operation: mvMatrixHandle and pMatrixHandle are defined previously
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, modelview);
glUniformMatrix4fv(pMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, projection);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Without, your answer might get flagged "low quality" and eventually removed. Stackoverflow does not take too kindly to link-only answers, as links might break and then the answer becomes worthless.